# Three.js b-spline fitting, how can i do it?

Tags: three.js, spline

I have large number of points in 3D space. I want to fit b-spline and display this spline with three.js. How can i do this? Preferably I want some tips or examples how to do it.

Comment: I have tried to create spline describing protein chain path. I know only points in 3d space from input data. I have to interpolate or aproximate them on spline. This spline i want to draw.

Comment: Did you check the three.js examples?